# How Does Entity Framework Code First Find Typed Entities From A Base-Class Set When Using TPC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

So this question might sound a little esoteric, but I've noticed something "magical" and I have a concern about the performance of what's going on under the hood. Assume I create entities using a TPC design, all entities inherit (directly or indirectly) from a root base entity, and the root base entity contains a globally unique identifier (such as a Guid) that is generated in code before saving (I.e., not generated by the database).

I would expect the following code to work by querying the table related to the coorisponding generic type to return a typed dynamic proxy (and it does):

`context.Set<ConcreteDerivedEntityClass>().Find(someGuid)`

However, I've also noticed that I can execute the following:

`context.Set<BaseEntityClass>().Find(someGuid)`

This is very cool and will magically return a typed dynamic proxy for the requested Id of the proper concrete class. How in the world does EF know which derived class / table the Id belongs to? Does it look at every table / entity type it knows about until it finds a match (hence the performance concern)?

Comment: Somewhat related? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821400/ef-linq-to-entities-query-generating-union-for-tpc-ctp5-code-first-entity Perhaps when performing a Set<BaseEntityClass>.Find() it is querying using a union over all possible derived types / tables... Can anyone confirm if this is the case?

Comment: This article should help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553510.aspx

Comment: You can find out using SQL Profiler.

Comment: As Julie Lerman says in the @ckal's link: "an inheritance hierarchy I had taught friends, loved ones and developers to avoid." Yes. EF looks at every table and the generated query can look really scary. This is improper use of inheritance. Not only because of querying, but also (mainly!) because of OO principles. It violates Liskov to begin with.

Comment: @ckal - Thanks, I thought that was a very good article with some good food for thought. Most importantly it did have some discussion of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @usr - I'll try using the SQL Profiler and post what I find as the answer (unless someone else beats me to it).

Comment: @GertArnold - I generally dislike answers/comments to questions here and on other message boards where someone asks a legitimate programming question and the answer is akin to "well, I don't know the answer, but you shouldn't do that anyway". There are many cases where a developer knows the best practice and has to deviate after careful consideration because of exotic requirements, legacy code, curiosity, etc.

Comment: "Does it look at every table / entity type it knows about until it finds a match (hence the performance concern)" My answer was: yes. _And_ I said don't do it just because no one can tell if you are aware of the issues and it is too bad if you aren't. That's what comments are for and that's why I did not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key of the inheriting table/entity is also a foreign key that points to the base table.

All it needs to do then is look at the classes that inherits from the base class. It probably cache the relationship in memory at load time somewhere too, to avoid the performance hit of reflection on every call, since the relationship is runtime static.

All that's left is to query the tables that matches the names of the child classes. This will be a *clustered index seek*, because of the requirement for inheritance. So while there's performance penalty it's insignificant considering the abstraction you gained.

EDIT:

BY default code first resort to Table per Hierarchy (TPH), which's 1 denormalized table, with an entity type coded in to the `Descriminator` column. In this case, the column tells EF what entity to typecast the result into.

The TPC mentioned above requires an additional code in the DBContext to specify the correct table mapping. It probably caches this in memory, and runs the routine already described above.